# Python Flask JSON KeyError

Tags: python, json, flask, keyerror

I'm trying to get some JSON data from another API service and update my flask app's database while user can download some PDF files. That API have 3 keys. 1st one is 'Status'. When that 'Status' key has `"success"` value, it also have other two keys and values too. Then app works fine without errors.
But when the 'Status' has the `'fail'` value, other two keys and values won't be there. I wrote a some exception but it doesn't work and end up with a KeyError, `KeyError: 'country'`

Here is my code.

```
    @app.route("/pdf/download/<int:pdf_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def downloads(pdf_id):
        current_ip = someIPaddress
        req = requests.request("GET", 'http://anotherwebsite.com/json/someIPaddress?fields=169')
        req_two = req.json()
        status = req_two['status']
        country = req_two['country']
        city = req_two['city']
        download_file = Pdf_info.query.get(pdf_id)
        if Ipaddress.query.filter(Ipaddress.ip_address == current_ip, Ipaddress.pdfid == pdf_id).first():
            try:
                return send_from_directory("pdfs/pdf/", filename=download_file.file_location_name, as_attachment=True)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                abort(404)
        else:
            if status == "success":
                ip_adding = Ipaddress(ip_address=current_ip, pdfid=pdf_id, downtime=datetime.utcnow(), country=country, location=city)
                db.session.add(ip_adding)
                db.session.commit()
                try:
                    return send_from_directory("pdfs/pdf/", filename=download_file.file_location_name, as_attachment=True)
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    abort(404)
            else:
                ip_adding = Ipaddress(ip_address=current_ip, pdfid=pdf_id, downtime=datetime.utcnow())
                db.session.add(ip_adding)
                db.session.commit()
                try:
                    return send_from_directory("pdfs/pdf/", filename=download_file.file_location_name, as_attachment=True)
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    abort(404)
```

Can someone explain why this doesn't work or mention a solution please ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to fetch:

```
country = req_two['country']
city = req_two['city']
```

before you have tested the output of:

```
status = req_two['status']
```

so if `status` is `fail` then  `country=` and `city=` will fail.

Use:

```
country = req_two.get('country')
city = req_two.get('city')
```

That will return `None` if the key is not found instead of a ``KeyError`. It also allows you test the` country`and`city` variables afterwards.

Comment: Thank you very much @Adrian Klaver , your solution worked.